# Merge duplicate and increase count for each object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, object

i have an array like this :

```
const studentList = [{code: "AA", gender:"male", DOB:"2000-05-15"},
{code: "AA", gender:"female", DOB:"2015-05-15"},
{code:"A0", gender:"female", DOB:"2005-01-01"},
{code: "A1", gender:"male", DOB:"2015-01-15"}]
```

the result i want is :
child is determine : Date.now().getFUllYear() - DOB.getFullYear() < 18 year

```
[{code:"AA", count:2, female: 1, child: 1},
{code:"A0", count: 1, female: 1, child: 1},
{code: "A1", count: 1, female: 0, child: 1}]
```

So far i have done something like this :

```
const result = new Map();
studentList.map(e =>{
    const isFemale = e.gender === "female";
    const isChild = nowYear - e.DOB.getYear() < 18;
    if(result.has(e.code) && isChild && isFemale){
       result.get(e.code).count++;
       result.get(e.code).female++;
       result.get(e.code).child++;
    }else if(!result.get(e.code && !isFemale && !isChild) {
       result.set(e.code, Object.assign(e,{count: 1, female: 0; child: 0 }))
    }
....
})
```

So on and for each condition i have to add a statement to the IF ELSE, so i wonder is there any shorter way to do it without using too much if else

Comment: Keep in mind this code is technically incorrect since birthdate isn't determined by year, but day and year.

Comment: yep, in my current code i converted them to timestamp to calculate. Just example here for the shorter code only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the feature that plus operator (+) converts boolean value `true` and `false` to number `1` and `0` respectively, and use `OR` (||) operator for assigning one of two values based on a condition, you can simplify your code as this:

```js
const studentList = [
{code: "AA", gender:"male", DOB:"2000-05-15"},
{code: "AA", gender:"female", DOB:"2015-05-15"},
{code:"A0", gender:"female", DOB:"2005-01-01"},
{code: "A1", gender:"male", DOB:"2015-01-15"}
];



const result = new Map();
var nowYear = new Date().getYear();

studentList.forEach(e =>{
    var item = result.get(e.code) || {code: e.code, count: 0, female: 0, child: 0 };
    item.count++;
    item.female += e.gender === "female";
    item.child += nowYear - new Date(Date.parse(e.DOB)).getYear() < 18;
    result.set(item.code, item);
})
 
for ([key, value] of result.entries()) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this solution, sorry my account do not have enough reputation to give you up vote